# 3D transforms are not displaying in Chrome on Windows XP

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a page with a series of cubes.  These cubes are transformed in 3D using CSS.

They display fine in Chrome on Windows 7, but in Chrome on Windows XP all I see is a white background.  Both are running the latest version of Chrome.

[View the full page on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rajkumart08/V8Xdn/1/embedded/result/)

```
<div class="cube" style="-webkit-transform: translateZ(-32.5px);">
    <div class="front" style="-webkit-transform: translateZ(32.5px);">
        <img src="search.png" width="65" height="65">
    </div>
    <div class="back" style="-webkit-transform: rotateX(-180deg) translateZ(32.5px);">
        <img src="search.png" width="65" height="65">
    </div>
    <div class="right" style="-webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(32.5px);">               
        <img src="/search.png" width="65" height="65">
    </div>
    <div class="left" style="-webkit-transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(32.5px);">
        <img src="search.png" width="65" height="65">
    </div>
    <div class="top" style="-webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(32.5px);">
        <img src="search.png" width="65" height="65">
    </div>
    <div class="bottom" style="-webkit-transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(32.5px);">
        <img src="search.png" width="65" height="65">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please specify what browsers you are viewing this on.

Comment: yeah i mentioned the chrome in my question itself

Comment: and the version of said chrome on each machine is: we wait for it...

Comment: This is the version Version 25.0.1364.160 m

Comment: Does the Windows XP machine have a graphics card/chipset capable of rendering the 3d transforms you're using? If it is old/cheap enough it may simply be incapable of the 3d rendering required.

Comment: I dont see any problem in my machine.. Please check in a different machine with XP

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Chrome will only properly render 3D css if GPU acceleration is enabled. If you test the same code on safari for windows it should work.

To see if your chrome has GPU acceleration enabled, type about:GPU into the address bar and see what it says.

http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/gpu-accelerated-compositing-in-chrome

Comment: i am talking with respect to xp and not windows 7

Comment: You are talking without reading the asnwers posted by others. Have you tested if Chrome in the XP machine has GPU acceleration enabled ? +1 to the answer

Comment: can you guys tell me how to test it

Comment: Go to your machine>>XP>>Start>> Run>> "dxdiag">> enter
---
this command will run a program inbuilt to check DX(Direct X) of your computer that will also show your GPU detail :)

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, perhaps you don't have a 3D Rendering enabled GPU, or maybe your graphics drivers don't support it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried modernizr?

Go to this page
http://modernizr.com/download/#-flexboxlegacy-csstransforms3d-shiv-cssclasses-addtest-prefixed-teststyles-testprop-testallprops-hasevent-prefixes-domprefixes-load

Click on the download below.

Use the JavaScript on your page.

If it will work the way I think, on you Win7 machine in Chrome the html tag should have a class of `csstransforms3d` and on the WinXP machine in Chrome  the html tag should have a class of `no-csstransforms3d`

I don't know if modernizr/chrome is that intelligent to see, if 3d acceleration is available and reflect it in the proper css class

### edit

Here's a fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/uSbYL/1/

Comment: thanks for your reply...how to test this part If it will work the way I think, on you Win7 machine in Chrome the html tag should have a class of csstransforms3d and on the WinXP machine in Chrome the html tag should have a class of no-csstransforms3d

Comment: You have to build a test html page where you insert the modernizr script with a `script` tag. Open it in your browser. Inspect the html with `F12` and elements. Look for the class attribute of the `html` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Follwing will work on chrome and firefox
CSS code

```
.flip-container {
  perspective: 1000;
  -webkit-perspective: 1000;
}
  /* flip the pane when hovered */
  .flip-container:hover .flipper, .flip-container.hover .flipper {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  }

.flip-container, .front, .back {
  float: left;
  height: 179px;
  margin-bottom: 49px;
  margin-left: 31px;
  width: 258px;
}

/* flip speed goes here */
.flipper {
  transition: 0.6s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transition: 0.6s;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  position: relative;
}

/* hide back of pane during swap */
.front, .back {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden; /* Chrome and Safari */
  -moz-backface-visibility:hidden; /* Firefox */
  -ms-backface-visibility:hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -42px;
}

/* front pane, placed above back */
.front {
  z-index: 2;
}

/* back, initially hidden pane */
.back {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

HTML code

```
<div class="flip-container" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
  <div class="flipper">
    <div class="product-box front">
       #front content
    </div>
    <div class="product-box back">
      #back content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```